# Ranges in for loop off by 1?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm working through the book automating the boring stuff with python and came across this code he wrote to find phone numbers within a document.

The format of phone numbers is (12 characters): 123-456-7890

Why does the code check if length of text is 12? but doesn't python count from 0 and so it'll look for a length of 13?

Similarly,
he wants to check if the first three digits are numbers but he uses a range(0, 3). Doesn't this check the first 4 digits including a hyphen which is not a number?

Thanks for the help.

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 12:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[3] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(4, 7):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[7] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(8, 12):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
           return False
    return True
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Then see the answer. I only posted a comment because I wasn't sure if that's what you were asking. They give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

[`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns the actual length of the string. Think of it, a string with length 0 (`""`) also exists.

The last value of [`range(start, end)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is `end-1`. The number 2 is in the range of `1-3` and the number 3 in the range of `3-5`. Inclusive bottom and exclusive upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to separate the concepts of *indexes* (the positions of objects in a list) and *length* (how many there are). Here's the doc of [len(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) in Python.

[range(start, stop)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) in Python includes the start and excludes the stop parameter. In mathematical notation, [start, stop). Therefore range(0,3) will check 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `len` function returns the number of objects in a list.
i.e.

```
>>> len([1, 2, 3])
3
```

`range(0, 3)` produces 0, 1, 2 and hence only checks the first three numbers.

```
>>> for i in range(0, 3):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting list indexing, the `len` function, and the `range` function confused.

List indexing starts at 0 and increases for each element. The 13th element in a list is at index 12, and would be accessed with `text[12]`.

The `len` function, on the other hand, returns the actual length of the list. The length of a 2-element is, of course, 2, and that's what `len` would return. In your example, the text is 13 characters long. `len` returns 13, but the last index of the text would be at `text[12]`.

The `range` function is *inclusive* of the starting value and *exclusive* of the ending value. In your example of `range(0, 3)`, it checks the items at locations 0, 1, and 2, *not* 0, 1, 2, and 3. If you want to check the first four numbers, use `range(0, 4)` instead, which will check the elements at list indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3, which are also the first, second, third, and fourth elements in the string.